# Jtable how to display data from mysql in different Columns

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I am trying to display data from the database in java using Jtable,  yes I  have achieved that but now the conflict is the surname and name they are  displayed in one Column yet I would like  them to be displayed in different columns . below is my code please help ..

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;

public class ju {
    private static Object request;
    static JTable mysTable;
    //constructor method

    public static void main (String args []){
    String [] columnNames = {"Name","Lastname","Id","Style"};
        mysTable = new JTable(4,4);
        mysTable.setBounds(20,10,300,300);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("King Musa Saloon Software");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setResizable(false);
           frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.add(mysTable);

//frame.add(mysTable);
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("Driver loading success!");
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/saloon";
            String name = "root";
            String password = "";
            try {


                java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, name, password);
                System.out.println("Connected.");
         // pull data from the database 
java.sql.Statement stmts = null;
String query = "select  userid, username, name from saloonuser ";
stmts = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmts.executeQuery(query);
int li_row = 0;
while(rs.next()){
    mysTable.setValueAt(rs.getString("username"),li_row,0);
    mysTable.setValueAt(rs.getString("name"),li_row,0);
    int userid = rs.getInt("userid");
    String username = rs.getString("username");
    String name1     = rs.getString("name");
    System.out.println(name1);
    li_row++;


}




            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Take a look at [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html). You should be adding rows to the table model instead of trying to update the cells via the table model, as the rows may not exists

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at your code here:

```
mysTable.setValueAt(rs.getString("username"),li_row,0);
mysTable.setValueAt(rs.getString("name"),li_row,0);
```

It's writing in the same column, you should change it to:

```
mysTable.setValueAt(rs.getString("username"),li_row,0);
mysTable.setValueAt(rs.getString("name"),li_row,1);
```

Try and see if it work :)

Comment: In life there are people whom we call super heroes , you one of them

Comment: How can I add headings of each column please @A-SM

Comment: I usually use this, look at your code here:  
`String [] columnNames = {"Name","Lastname","Id","Style"};  
mysTable = new JTable(4,4);`  

I convert it to:  

`Object [] columnNames = {"Name","Lastname","Id","Style"};  
mysTable = new JTable(columnNames,4);`

Comment: So should I use this only Object [] columnNames = {"Name","Lastname","Id","Style"}; mysTable = new JTable(columnNames,4); @A-SM

Comment: it says constructor JTable(Object int) undefined

Comment: sorry, I forgot it should be `mysTable=new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 4))` :)